# How to say "well done"?

Tags: idiom

Is there a Latin phrase similar to the English "well done!" to be used to congratulate someone for achieving something?
Translating from English, one might expect *bene factum!* or *bene fecisti!* or something similar, or just a plain adverb (*bene!*, *egregie!*, *optime!*...), but I have never encountered any such thing in use.
Is there a set phrase for this purpose?

Comment: If I remember correctly, teachers tended to use _multa bene_ or _optime_ for this purpose, but I do not know of any specific/official source for this information.

Comment: @SamK I remember teachers using plain adverbs (which I added to the question), but it would be nice to see what more native speakers would use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Macte* (voc. of *[mactus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=macte&la=la#lexicon)* - from Greek [μάκαρ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ma%2Fkar&la=greek&can=ma%2Fkar0&prior=mak)) is used in this way, with or without with *esto*.  According to Lewis & Short, it can be used alone (*Macte!*) but it is much more commonly used with *virtute*.

> *“macte virtute esto” sanguinolentis ex acie redeuntibus dicitur*
>
> it is to the blood-stained soldier returning from the front that men
>   cry: “Well done!”

Seneca the Younger, *Epistles*, 66

> *‘Oratorem’ legas? macte virtute!*
>
> You're reading *The Orator*?  Well done!

Cicero, *Letters to Atticus*, 243 (XII.6a)

Comment: Your write that *macte* is the ablative of *mactus*. Judging by L&S, it's a vocative. This looks like a very interesting saying, much in the spirit of "well done!", but I seem to have difficulties parsing it syntactically.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Oops!  You're right, macte!  I've changed it accordingly.  I agree, it is odd, very idiomatic.

Comment: [At least one grammar book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ThZLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA232) says in a footnote, "[*macte*] is generally, but without good reason, considered as the vocative of an adjective otherwise unused." The L&S entry, though, seems to have at least one example of *mactus* in the nominative, from Cato.

Comment: [Allen & Greenough](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/vocative), though, wants to have it both ways: it initially describes it as vocative, but adds in an aside, "As the original quantity of the final e in macte is not determinable, it may be that the word was an adverb, as in bene est and the like."

Comment: The quality of the vowel is short in Vergil, Statius et al. (checked with [pedecerto](http://www.pedecerto.eu/lessico/lessico/check/ricerca)). It still doesn't exclude it being an adverbial form of *mactis*, an ablative of the same agreeing with *virtūte*, or a derivative of *mag-* "big".

Answer (score 10):

In questions of spoken Latin, Plautus is my go-to. One good term for this, frequent in Plautus, is [***euge***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Deuge), from the Greek [εὖγε](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Deu)%3Dge). A [corpus search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23euge%23) reveals quite a few examples, often with native Latin repetitions:

> **Euge euge, lepide, laudo** commentum tuom. (*Miles Gloriosus*)
>
> **Euge, euge**, exornatu's basilice; (*Persa*)

(great adverb!)

There are many other excellent choices, but I'll leave those for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about: te laudo; or, if you are really proud of your student: te amo; but, in the current climate, that could be misunderstood.

Comment: If one uses *te amo* with a student, there is a chance they'll ask how to translate "me too" to Latin.